# Excel time format auto-change issue

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm currently working on an Excel application that can get info from my Form worksheet and display it into Display worksheet. So far the data can transfer perfectly, except for one tiny quirk.

The Display worksheet will display data when Execute is clicked.
Here is the screenshot:
[image: Here is the screenshot.]

Before I execute the Display, the Time field in the Form worksheet is formatted as h:mm AM/PM. However, when I click Execute in Display worksheet, the Time format suddenly changed in the Form Worksheet as seen here:
[image: as seen here.]

Furthermore the change in format is also seen in the Display table as well. I tried setting the format to be identical for both worksheets and the result is still the same.

Is it the issue of the SQL1 statement or the coding in general? here is the code sample.

```
Public Sub QueryWorksheet(szSQL As String, rgStart As Range, wbWorkBook As String, AB As String)
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim szConnect As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If AB = "1st" Then
wbWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inner Workings").Range("B9").Text
End If

Application.StatusBar = "Retrieving data ....."
'Set up the connection string to excel - thisworkbook
szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & wbWorkBook & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
'Run the query as adCmdText
rsData.Open szSQL, szConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'Check if data is returned
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    'if the recordset contains data put them on the worksheet
    rgStart.CopyFromRecordset rsData
Else

End If
'Close connection
rsData.Close
'Clean up and get out
Set rsData = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
'an error occured in the SQL-statement
MsgBox "Your query could not be executed, the SQL-statement is incorrect."
Set rsData = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Sub process()
Call clear
Call testsql("1st")  ' populate 1st Summary
Call testsql("2nd")  ' find Date+Time
Call testsql("3rd")   ' GET LATEST RECORD
End Sub

Sub testsql(AB As String)

Dim rgPlaceOutput As Range       'first cell for the output of the query
Dim stSQLstring As String     'text of the cell containing the SQL statement
Dim rg As String, SQL As String

If AB = "1st" Then
stSQLstring = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inner Workings").Range("B2").Text
Set rgPlaceOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1st Summary").Range("A2")
End If
If AB = "2nd" Then
stSQLstring = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inner Workings").Range("B3").Text
Set rgPlaceOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2nd Summary").Range("A2")
End If
If AB = "3rd" Then
stSQLstring = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inner Workings").Range("B4").Text
Set rgPlaceOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final Summary").Range("A5")
End If

QueryWorksheet stSQLstring, rgPlaceOutput, ThisWorkbook.FullName, AB

End Sub

Sub clear()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1st Summary").Range("A2:BR5000").Value = Empty
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2nd Summary").Range("A2:BR5000").Value = Empty
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final Summary").Range("A2:BR5000").Value = Empty
End Sub
```

If anyone can help with this, I greatly appreciate it.

Update:

Apparently, this quirk is larger than I thought. After more testing I found out that the second summary sheet is also affected as well as seen here. [image: as seen here]. Albeit the lower half at least. The mystery keeps piling up...

Comment: PS. Sorry for the inconvenient screenshots. I don't have enough points to show images on post. :p

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at NumberFormat iirc add something like "DD/MM/YYYY" to a Range (columns in your case). I'm on a Mac with Office 365, and although VBA is now in the app, the sort of intellisense is absent so unless you know the Excel Object model by heart it's a royal PITA!