# Excel SQL import - date format not appearing and time format auto-change. Annoying

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm working on a Excel application that will obtain data from my Entry form and import it into a Display sheet, both in separate worksheets.

The Entry form has a table to key in data via a combination of manual key-in, dropdown lists and vlookup functions. This table is then defined as EntryTable.[image].

In the Summary form there is an SQL statement (SQL1) used to import the data from Entry to Display.
[image]

However every time I click the button, the Entry Date will not appear, and the Time changes its format to include date and time.
[image]

What's more for some reason the time format in Entry also changes as well. To add insult to injury.
[image]

Basically my question here is:

1. Why was Entry Date omitted in the search even though the SQL specifically stated to select all?
2. Why does the time always have to add a date in the format every time I try to import?

If anyone know what the issue is, please share with me. Because I'm all out of ideas and I'm losing my patience.

Comment: Is this question different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298477/6535336)?

Comment: yes its the same. but the Entry date issue just came up today and I feel like adding it to the original post would make it more difficult to follow. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: FWIW - The "adding" of the date to your time field is a reformatting issue only - e.g. a time of 6:00AM is the number 0.25 (i.e. 1/4 of the way through day 0, where day 0 is 0th January 1900) which when formatted as "d/m/yyyy" instead of as "hh:mm AM/PM" becomes "0/1/1900"

Comment: I see. But how to stop it from doing that? I want to show it in that h:mm AM/PM format.